# Why does nodeExists() throw BackingStoreException

Tags: java, preferences

Simple question: I am wondering why the `Preferences` method `nodeExists()` throws a `BackingStoreException` that must be caught? What would cause a `BackingStoreException` exactly, and of all the methods in the `Preferences` API, why does **this method** (and not all of the others) require it to be caught?

Reading this paragraph from the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) docs does not help me much:

> All of the methods that read preferences from a Preferences object require the invoker to provide a default value. The default value is returned if no value has been previously set or if the backing store is unavailable. The intent is to allow applications to operate, albeit with slightly degraded functionality, even if the backing store becomes unavailable. Several methods, like flush, have semantics that prevent them from operating if the backing store is unavailable. Ordinary applications should have no need to invoke any of these methods, which can be identified by the fact that they are declared to throw BackingStoreException.

Maybe I don't understand it, but wouldn't the unavailability of the backing store be a risk for all `Preferences` methods? The paragraph above makes me think I am calling a method I "should have no need to invoke." Yet checking if a node exists seems like it'd be a common operation to me.

Every time I call `nodeExists()` I have to add a `try / catch` block around it and handle the exception.

Answer (score 1):

`nodeExists` can throw a `BackingStoreException` because it *requires* access to the backing store to determine whether a node exists.  You don't normally need to know a priori whether or not a node exists, as calling `node(pathName)` or the static `*NodeForPackage` will automatically create it and its ancestors if required, and I would have thought this would be the more usual mode of operation for clients of the preferences API - get "your" node (creating it if necessary) and the store and/or load values in the node using the various `get` and `put` methods.

The methods that obtain nodes (`node`, `userRoot`, etc.) do *not* throw `BackingStoreException` because if the backing store is unavailable they can still proceed by giving you an empty node.  Any `get` calls on that node will simply ignore the values in the backing store and give you the default values you provided, and any `put` calls will fail to persist (unless the backing store becomes available again before the node is flushed).  The preferences API is only ever a "best effort" system, designed to gracefully degrade wherever possible by returning default values rather than throwing exceptions.

Comment: How can the methods that obtain nodes proceed without a backing store? I guess I'm a little confused as to what a backing store is, and why some operations can proceed without it...

Comment: The intended use case for preferences is to store stuff like the list of recently opened documents, the position of the window last time it was closed, the directory from which to start the file chooser, etc. i.e. things that improve the user experience but which are not critical to the correct functioning of the application.  If the backing store (the registry on Windows, files on disk for other platforms) is unavailable for any reason the app will still work but the user will just get the default values rather than their personal preferences.